# MySQL "ALTER IGNORE TABLE" Error In Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the query:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE test_table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

test_table is just a temporary table I'm using for testing purposes, and id is a column in it.

The query works fine without the "IGNORE" key word, but when I add it I get the error message:

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE TABLE test_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)' at line 1"

How do I fix this? Or how can I run that query and ignore any errors that might occur? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, so I can't check, but I believe your use of "ignore" is incorrect. Check the manual page about it on the mysql site ;)

Comment: [As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: Ah that was the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error. Please check your version

Comment: Yes that is the issue. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the recommended way to perform the same operation without IGNORE?