# Using Alter and ignore in mysql to remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MYSQL and have a table 'bid' which has duplicates entries into it 
My table schema is

```
ITEM_CODE   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Max_BidP    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Seller_Name | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Buyer_Name  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ITEM_NAME   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Qty         | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

One of the entries in the table

```
16 |       30 | sahraw       | sahraw       | J.K Rowling |    1 |
16 |       30 | sahraw       | sahraw       | J.K Rowling |    1 |
```

I am trying to remove the dulicates and the query I am specifying is

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE bid ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ITEM_CODE , Max_BidP ,Seller_Name  , Buyer_Name   , ITEM_NAME ,   Qty);
```

But its giving me an error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE TABLE bid ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ITEM_CODE , Max_BidP ,Seller_Nam' at line 1

Any suggestions where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: what version of mysql? "IGNORE" was removed as of 5.7.4, maybe earlier

Answer (score 0):

Please check the MySQL version you are using.

As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: am using 5.7.15. Is there some other way to handle this duplicate situation in later versions

Comment: For later versions, you can first delete the duplicate rows and then create the index

Comment: How do you delete duplicate rows?

Comment: Here's a way that worked for me: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/ (But be careful not to delete ALL of the rows)
What also helped me is to realise that phpMyAdmin has an option in the settings to en-/disable editing for tables without primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySql 5.7.4 or later, `IGNORE` is no longer available. See [MySQL “ALTER IGNORE TABLE” Error In Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972695/mysql-alter-ignore-table-error-in-syntax)

Comment: I am using 5.7.15. Is there some other way to handle this duplicate situation in later versions